# Divs with flex property overlaps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I am using angular and angular-material to create a custom directive. All is correct except that when I add a flex attribute in the directive link function to one div the content get overlapped.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9crdbz4t/

```
<div layout="row">
    <div flex=10>example.long.email@example.com.zzz</div>
    <div flex>Some other text that require more space</div>
</div>
```

How can I adjust to content if it's greater that the flex value?

Comment: Maybe add word-wrap: break-word; in the first Div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex-box wont break consecutive text. But you have here an elegant solution. By this way you can avoid overlapping.

```
<div flex layout="row" >
    <div flex="10" style="text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">example.long.email@example.com.zzz</div>
    <div flex >Some other text that require more space</div>
</div>
```

Or you can just use `word-wrap: break-word;`.

```
<div  layout="row" >
        <div flex="10" style="word-wrap: break-word;">example.long.email@example.com.zzz</div>
        <div flex >Some other text that require more space</div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9crdbz4t/13/

Comment: thank you, both solutions could help in differents scenarios